# Does partial maximization/minimization always give the the same result as global optimization?

Tags: statistics, optimization, maximum-likelihood

Suppose I want to optimize the function,f(x), where x is a vector. x can be seperated into two sub-vectors, $(x)=(x_{1},x_{2})$.

I can first partially optimize $x_{1}$, and treat $x_{2}$ as constant, so that I get the optimal $x^{*}_{1}$ as a function of $x_{2}$.Then I can optimize the object function as a function of $x_{2}, i.e. f(x^{*}_{1}(x_{2}),x_{2})$.

My question is does this always give the same result, as I directly optimize f(x) over x? Can this be proved?

The question arised from the maximum likelihood estimation of normal distribution, where $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are all unknown. We always calculate $\hat{\mu}$ first, then express $\hat{\sigma}$ as a function of $\hat{\mu}$. I want to know does this procedure can be applied to any kind of problem?

Comment: Yes, this is true. You can argue that if $(x^*_1,x^*_2)$ is an optimal solution of the joint problem, then for $x_2$ fixed to $x^*_2$, we have that $x_1 = x^*_1$ is an optimal solution to the inner problem. However, note that the outer optimization for $x_2$ might become more challenging than jointly optimizing over $(x_1,x_2)$ because $x^*_1(x_2)$ might be non-smooth or even discontinuous in general.